# Ant execution timeout doesn't terminate task

Tags: ant, timeout, exec

I am using following ant task:

```
<target name="task">
    <exec executable="grunt.cmd" dir="adir" failonerror="true" timeout="1000">      
        <arg value="test" />
        <arg value="-v" />
    </exec>     
</target>
```

I want the ant task to be terminated after one second. But it does not affect any changes. The tasks runs through. After finishing the task, the following message occurs:

> Timeout: killed the sub-process

But the timeout is completely ignored.

Any ideas regarding to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually cmd files are executed via `<exec executable="cmd">`, also try setting spawn attribute, f.e :

```
<exec executable="cmd" dir="adir" failonerror="true" timeout="1000" spawn="true">
  <arg value="/c"/>
  <arg value="grunt.cmd"/>
  <arg value="test"/>
  <arg value="-v"/>
</exec>
```

Otherwise ant will wait for the process to complete because it collects stdout/stderr output.
Alternatively use :

```
<parallel threadcount="1" timeout="1000">
 <exec executable="cmd" dir="adir" failonerror="true">
  <arg value="/c"/>
  <arg value="grunt.cmd"/>
  <arg value="test"/>
  <arg value="-v"/>
 </exec>
</parallel>
```